# Frameset menu in HTML

Tags: html, css, frameset

I am having two `framesets` at a `HTML page`.
The idea is to have all my menus in the first frameset and when user clicks on the menu link the target page should be there in the second frameset. However I am able to achieve this but the problem is that whole menu dropdown are not overlapping on the page, it means that the menu dropdown is restricted to the first frameset only and user needs to scroll down to see the whole menu.
I am tried using `z-index` property but is not working for me. Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us some code please

Answer (score 0):

If something is inside a frameset, it **cannot** display out of it.

What i mean:

```
+---------------------------------+
| Frameset 1                      |
| Menu1                           |
|  Option1                        |
|  Option2                        |
+---------------------------------+
+---------------------------------+
| Frameset 2                      |
|                                 |
| Content                         |
| Content                         |
+---------------------------------+
```

If there were Option3, Option4, Option5 etc... they could **NOT** be displayed out of Frameset1 and over the Frameset 2. **It's not possible by-design.**